# svgicons2svgfont - Nonwhitespace before first tag

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, sax

Facing some issue with svgicons2svgfont library. https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgicons2svgfont
When running the command **npm run icons** it does not convert my SVG's to font and it drops me this error:

> Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.

And in the start after i run the command it shows me this

> ttf2woff2/jssrc/ttf2woff2.js:3 Invalid asm.js: Invalid member of
> stdlib

My webpack config looks like this

```
{
    test: /\.svg$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(SOURCE_ROOT + SVG_ICON_PATH)
    ],
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name]-[hash].[ext]',
          outputPath: //correctUrl here,
          publicPath: //correctUrl here
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Checked every open issue that might be related to this one.

Also, tried upgrading the library to latest version and downgrading to some previous versions, nothing helped

Comment: Your icon svg might contain invalid markup or custom/application specific properties, comments etc. I'd recommend to try also antoher icon source like [FontAwesome icons](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/sprites/regular.svg) – just to make sure the issue is not related to e.g an incomplete setup/install. You should also add a svg code snippet containing only one icon.

Comment: @herrstrietzel I checked the SVG's with hex editor and there is no special character. Not sure whats the problem, but i am guessing that it has to do with the SVG's structure, it contains 2 paths and maybe the library is confused

Comment: You might also try the [online generator](http://nfroidure.github.io/svgiconfont). If it works with your icon svg, then you setup might have issues (missing dependencies etc)